# React Redux error when importing same file to multiple reducers

Tags: ios, react-native, react-redux

I have the following code to combine my reducers using react/redux and everything works fine.

```
combineReducers({
  curriculum: CurriculumReducer,
  otherReducer: OtherReducer,
})
```

Currently I import with the code below in CurriculumReducer the 'initial' data file.

```
import Data from './initial'
```

When I try to also import this file into otherReducer. I get an error that 'curriculum' cannot be undefined. So somehow importing this in both of these locations is causing the initialization of the reducer file to fail.

Anyone have any ideas what the heck is going on here.

Also to clear this up if in my main file of my app before initializing my store I import the 'initial.js' file this error goes away.

Comment: Can you post the whole content of the file where you call combineReducers ? as well as more content on the reducer files you are trying to combine and the initial.js file ? And especially how you use the Data object in both reducer files.

Oh and the relative position of the reducers files to the initial file. Is it the same for both reducers (in the same folder )?

Comment: Yea I can't upload the actual source. But I have narrowed it down to be something to do w/ some middle ware. We are using async storage and thunks. Digging more into this thought it was more generic.